# Big box beside 4 small boxes using R

Tags: shiny

I want to create 4 small boxes in a 2x2 fashion beside one big box to show one important graph and 4 less important beside it but I cant get the small boxes to place correctly.

```
box(width = 6, height = '300px', solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
        title = "Victim Nationality"
        #Plot
      ),

    column( 3,
    box(width = 3, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
        title = " "
        #Plot
        ),
    box(width = 3, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
        title = " "
        #Plot
    )
    ),
    column(3,
    box(width = 3, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
        title = " "
        #Plot
        ),
    box(width = 3, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
        title = " "
        #Plot
        )
    )
```

If I change box to wellPanel it will work but I would prefer to be able to do it with box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the whole expression in another `column` as follows,

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


header = dashboardHeader(title ="Test Page")

sidebar = dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                                       menuItem("Test Tab",tabName = "test_tab")))

test_tab = tabItem(tabName = "test_tab",
                   box(width = 6, height = '50vh', solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
                       title = "Victim Nationality"
                       #Plot
                   ),
                   column(6,
                          fluidRow(

                            box(width = 6,height = '25vh', solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
                                title = "Tab 1"
                                #Plot
                            ),
                            box(width = 6,height = '25vh', solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
                                title = "Tab 2"
                                #Plot
                            )

                          ),
                          fluidRow(

                           box(width = 6,height = '25vh', solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
                               title = "Tab 3"
                               #Plot
                           ),
                           box(width = 6,height = '25vh', solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
                               title = "Tab 4"
                               #Plot
                           )

                          )
                      )

                   )

body = dashboardBody(tabItems(test_tab))

ui = dashboardPage(title = "Test App",header,sidebar,body)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```